При подключении по SSH с помощью Windows PowerShell с Windows 11 к Mac OS X кириллица выводится знаками вопроса
Я нашел несколько решений вот тут, например но ничего из этого не помогает. Шрифты менял, в локали кодировку менял на UTF-8, и вот это вот [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 тоже применял. Безрезультатно.
При попытке ввода кириллицы часть символов вводится нормально, а часть вот так - <0080>, <008b>...

Покончите, наконец, с виндой

А если наоборот 866ю поставить?

Они только не выводятся или не работают?

@Qwertiy при попытке ввести название файла, которое записано в кириллице, выяснилось, что какая-то часть кириллицы вводится нормально, а какая-то типа того - <0080><008b> и т.д.

Я не это спросил.

@Qwertiy а как мне проверить работают они или нет если я не могу их название ввести?

@AlexeyTrukhanov, ну выведи какой-нибудь файл на консоль. Если он найдёт файл несмотря на то, что в консоли показаны вопросики, значит работает. А если выдаст ошибку, что нет такого файла - значит не работает. Предполагается, что ты знаешь какой-то файл, который точно есть на сервере, а не создаёшь его по ssh.

@Qwertiy Вы извините, что я настолько туплю, но я все равно не понимаю как я могу "вывести файл на консоль" если я не в состоянии напечатать в консоли его название. Название-то  я знаю, а что толку.

@AlexeyTrukhanov, на так берёшь и печатаешь, независимо от того, какие символы выводятся. Только без опечаток.

@Qwertiy выводится.

@AlexeyTrukhanov, а выводится в какой кодировке?

@Qwertiy так как я не знаю как непосредственно посмотреть кодировку (может подскажете?) я провел эксперимент - я создал файл на сервере (не через SSH, а непосредственно на нем, как на локальной машине) с кириллическим названием, а в содержимом я напечатал кириллический алфавит заглавные и строчные. Потом все это вывел в консоль на клиентской машине через SSH - все выводится нормально. Только в конце вывода ставит знак процента.
